# Loop to dynamically fill dataframe R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am running a for loop to fill dynamically a dataframe (I know a baby seal dies somewhere because I am using a for loop)

I have something like this in mind (the 5 is a placeholder for a function that returns a scalar):

```
results<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(seq(1:10)), ncol = 
length(seq(1:10))))
rows<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1))
for (j in seq(1:10)){
rows<-data.frame()
for (i in seq(1:10)){
   rows<-cbind(rows,5)
}
results<-cbind(results,rows)
}
```

I get the following error message with my approach above.

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
names do not match previous names
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: you're overwriting `rows`. is that causing the error? What should the data-frame look like at the end - if all 5s then do data.frame(matrix(5, nrow = 10, ncol = 10))?

Comment: sorry, forgot the error message.

Comment: the 5 is a placeholder for a function that returns a scalar

Comment: I am deliberately overwriting rows, I only want that function to fill that one row, pass that on to the results dataframe, and start over

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dynamically *filling* an object using a for loop is fine - what causes problems is when you dynamically *build* an object using a for loop (e.g. using `cbind` and `rbind` rows).

When you build something dynamically, R has to go and request new memory for the object in each loop, because it keeps increasing in size. This causes a for loop to slow down with every iteration as the object gets bigger.

When you create the object beforehand (e.g. a `data.frame` with the right number of rows and columns), and fill it in by index, the for loop doesn't have this problem.

One final thing to keep in mind is that for `data.frames` (and `matrices`) each column is stored as a vector in memory – so its usually more efficient to fill these in one column at a time.

With all that in mind we can revise your code as follows:

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(seq(1:10)), 
                                 ncol = length(seq(1:10))))
for (rowIdx in 1:nrow(results)) {
  for (colIdx in 1:ncol(results)) {
    results[rowIdx, colIdx] <- 5 # or whatever value you want here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your intention. Now keeping your intention and way of implementation a way to fix the problem to change `for-loop` so that `rows` is initialized with 1st value. The second `for-loop` should be from `seq(2:10)`.

The error is occurring because attempting to `cbind` a blank `data.frame` with valid value.

```
for (j in seq(1:10)){
  rows<-data.frame(5)    #Initialization with 1st value
  for (i in seq(2:10)){  #Loop 2nd on wards. 
    rows<-cbind(rows,5)
  }
  results<-cbind(results,rows)
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you are absolutely right. I missed that one, thank you!!